# c# How to Delete dataGridView Row from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I need to delete a DataGridView row from another thread.

This code works only if I delete it from the same thread.

```cs
public void DeletedataGridView1(string text)
{
    // See if a new invocation is required form a different thread
    if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback h = new SetTextCallback(AdddataGridView1);
        this.Invoke(h, new object[] { text });

    }
    else
    {
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow row0 in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 && row0.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                if (row0.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(text))
                {   
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row0.Index);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Another thread:

```
myform.DeletedataGridView1("X");
```

This doesn't work for me, row doesn't get deleted. Please help

Comment: You need to remove using an instance of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: could you be a little more specific please? im not too sure what it means "instance of the form". Is it like "public Form1 myform; Level2.Form1 formed;?" or is it something else?

Comment: The link show the two form classes Form1 and Form2.  The instances are form1 and form2.

Comment: What is this *other Thread*? Did you start it? Or are you handling events raised in a Thread other that the UI Thread? Can you pass a `Progress<T>` delegate to this *Thread*? -- What is `SetTextCallback()`? Why are checking `InvokeRequired` to then do, apparently, two different things if it is?

Comment: Did you try `if (this.InvokeRequired)`?